# How to update a number field in child case from parent case

Tags: trigger

I need to update child case from parent case.

After creating child case, when ever the number field is updated in parent i need same field to get updated in child case.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: did you look at Process Builder?

Comment: What if there are multiple child cases, what is the value of the field then? How do you know which child case the number goes with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use process builder. Lets say you want to update phone on contact when there is change in account phone number..Create a process builder on account.. Add criteria as follows:

[image]

Immediate action will be 
[image]

Make sure to activate your process builder :)

Comment: N.B. - will update all child Contacts with the Account phone number

Comment: Ya thats correct. If he wants to update any particular child record, he has to add some condition or trigger, may be...